# What should be the dimension of the cases that are used for Pi-Zero1.3?

Tags: pi-zero, case

I am using BLE4.0 and Microphone on my pi-zero. What are the case dimensions required?

Comment: The question about cooling was incoherent and tangential so I have removed it.  No one can tell you what cooling is required unless you have an overheating problem you can describe in concrete terms.  If so, please use a separate question to do so.  If you do not have an overheating problem you can describe in concrete terms, you do not require any cooling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the official *Mechanical Drawings* on [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#) where they provide - unfortunately - only the [schematics of the Pi Zero, Rev 1.2 (pdf)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416012949/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/rpi-zero-v1_2_dimensions.pdf). Rev 1.3 however differs only in one aspect: it has an additional fine-pitch connector for the camera, see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/zero-grows-camera-connector/) (with photographs and everything). This connector sticks out on one side of the PCB for about 1 mm and a length of 17 mm (see crude adapted schematics below).

[image: Pi Zero Rev 1.3]

<sup><sub>[Source, modified](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416012949/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/rpi-zero-v1_2_dimensions.pdf)</sub></sup>

So this is the Pi that has to fit into your housing. As for the additional components, well that is completely up to you as we do not know anything about their dimensions.